# Why does dispatch_once only get called for the first instance of class?

Tags: objective-c, static, scope

In my UITableViewCell subclass, I have the following code:

```
-(void)updateConstraints
{   
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
    // Set constraints here
    });

    [super updateConstraints];
}
```

The constraints are only set for the first instance of the custom cell class. I don't really understand what's happening with the static token. I was under the impression that it is an instance-specific variable, but apparently it is class-scoped. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `once` is neither a instance variable, nor a static class variable.

It's a static variable with scope local to the `updateConstraints` method. It's visible only within that method, gets created the first time `updateConstraints` is called, and has a lifetime that extends through the end of the program. In other words, `once` keeps its value between calls to `updateConstraints`.

The `dispatch_once` function uses this fact to ensure the block gets run exactly once.

Comment: Then why can I have that block of code in two different classes, and it will run once for each class?

Comment: It's because they're two different methods. I'll use C++ syntax, since I don't know of a quick way of expressing this idea in Objective C. If you have two classes, ClassA and ClassB, then `ClassA::updateConstraints` and `ClassB::updateConstraints` are not the same function.

Comment: I see...so you can have static variables that are tied to functions. I only thought variables could belong to classes or objects. Thanks for the insight.